# XSLT: for-each loop with key not returning all nodes

Tags: xslt, xpath, foreach, missing-data

I am a novice XSLT developer.  I have been asked to fix an issue on a project where the original developer is no longer with us.  In the XSLT, there is a `for-each` loop using a `key` and a `count`

```
<xsl:for-each select="ns0:BOM[count(. | key('subsat', ns0:BomText01)[1]) = 1][ns0:BomText01]"> 
   ...
```

This is the `key`:

```
<xsl:key name="subsat" match="ns0:Parts/ns0:BOM[ns0:FindNum!='0']" use="ns0:BomText01" />
```

In the XML file being transformed, there are two sibling nodes that represent sub-parts:

```
<ns0:BOM referentId="10000:65091335:65359080">
  <ns0:BomText01>3069260-303-SUB0027</ns0:BomText01> 
  <ns0:ItemNumber>My_part_1</ns0:ItemNumber> 
  <ns0:ItemType>Part</ns0:ItemType> 
  <ns0:Qty>67</ns0:Qty> 
</ns0:BOM>
<ns0:BOM referentId="10000:65102551:86713230">
  <ns0:BomText01>3069260-303-SUB0027</ns0:BomText01> 
  <ns0:ItemNumber>My_part_2</ns0:ItemNumber> 
  <ns0:ItemType>Part</ns0:ItemType> 
  <ns0:Qty>67</ns0:Qty> 
</ns0:BOM>
```

However, the loop is only picking up the first node (`My_part_1`).  I suspect it's because of the `count=1` but I really don't know.  And I don't know how to modify it.  Ideas?  If I need to include more data, let me know.

Comment: Please include the full context of your XML source (parent elements, namespace declarations, etc.) and all the relevant templates of your XSLT document (includes root node, key declarations, the complete for-each above & inside it template, and any other templates that are called)

Comment: @Helderdarocha...I wish I could but it's proprietary content.  It might take me hours to carve it up and make it generic. Do you have any suggestion on how the count works in the foreach?

Comment: Ok. I will take a look. Also your `key` seems invalid. It has to be a valid *qualified name* - it wouldn't start with a number. Are you being able to run it at all? What processor are you using?

Comment: Thanks!  I'll grab the key protion of the XSLT.  I just put that text in there cause I think that's what it is using.

Comment: I posted an answer. Perhaps you can apply it to your actual example. The `count` expression with the key is actually used to select unique values, so in your example it would only select the first one, since both have the same `BomText01`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that *the relevant part* of your XSLT looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:ns0="ns0" version="1.0">

    <xsl:key name="subsat" match="ns0:BOM[ns0:FindNum!='0']" use="ns0:BomText01"/>

    <xsl:template match="ns0:Parts">
        <xsl:for-each 
            select="ns0:BOM[count(. | key('subsat', ns0:BomText01)[1]) = 1][ns0:BomText01]">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It will only print the first of the elements because it is selecting the `BOM` elements which have an *unique* `BomText01` value. That's the *expected* result.

If the `BomText01` is an ID field (as it seems it is) and you expected to get both result (perhaps, because their `ItemNumber` contains different values), the error is possibly in your source (which assigned equal IDs when it should not have done so).

If you change one of those values in the source, you should be able to select both and verify this.

Comment: @Held...I give the source a look.  Thanks

Comment: @Held...I found the answer.  I modifed the =1 to be >= 1 in the for-each.  That gathered all sibling nodes with BomText01 having the same key value as 'subsat'

Comment: @Help...I'm going to up vote your answer because it was educational for me.  I don't know if accepting it is the right thing since the >=1 was the answer.  Thanks for the feedback, though